# Chome Linear-Gradient css

Tags: html, css, sass

Wondering if anyone can give some pointers.
I have a linear gradient that works perfectly fine in Firefox, and understand there are some bugs that still aren't fixed with chrome.

Essentially I have narrowed it down to the fact that the chromium engine may not be able to process too many steps in a linear-gradient very well.

Gradient 1 - Works fine for both Chrome + Firefox

```css
background: linear-gradient(
            140deg,
            rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 2%,
            rgba(47, 68, 95, 1) 2%,
            rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 5%,
            rgb(54, 80, 114) 5%,
            rgba(107, 149, 177, 1) 50%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 86%,
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 94%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 94%,
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 97%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 97%,
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 99%
        );
```

[image]

But when you add another step, it blurs all the edges.

```css
background: linear-gradient(
            140deg,
            rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 2%,
            rgba(47, 68, 95, 1) 2%,
            rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 5%,
            rgb(54, 80, 114) 5%,
            rgba(39, 48, 56, 1) 9%, // the new step
            rgba(107, 149, 177, 1) 50%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 86%,
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 94%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 94%,
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 97%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 97%,
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 99%
        );
```

[image]

Heres a link on JSFiddle to show it properly.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xwn031pk/)

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

div.one {
  background: linear-gradient(
        140deg,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 2%,
        rgba(47, 68, 95, 1) 2%,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 5%,
        rgb(54, 80, 114) 5%,
        rgba(107, 149, 177, 1) 50%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 86%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 94%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 94%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 97%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 97%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 99%
    );
}

div.two {  
    background: linear-gradient(
        140deg,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 2%,
        rgba(47, 68, 95, 1) 2%,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 5%,
        rgb(54, 80, 114) 5%,
    rgba(39, 48, 56, 1) 9%,
        rgba(107, 149, 177, 1) 50%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 86%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 94%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 94%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 97%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 97%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 99%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated, other than the jagged edges, I know how to remove them using calc().

==== Working code ====
Special thanks too @Temani Afif

```css
/* This is the working code with calc edges to prevent jaggering */
background: linear-gradient(
            140deg,
            rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 0%,
            rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 2%,
            rgba(47, 68, 95, 1) calc(2% + 1px),
            rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 5%,
            rgb(54, 80, 114) calc(5% + 1px),
            rgba(39, 48, 56, 1) 9%,
            rgb(54, 115, 150) 50%,transparent 0
            ),
           linear-gradient(140deg,
            rgb(54, 115, 150) 50%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 86%,
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 94%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) calc(94% + 1px),
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 97%,
            rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) calc(97% + 1px),
            rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 99%
           );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue on chrome, the fix is to split to multiple gradient:

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

div.two {  
    background: linear-gradient(
        140deg,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 2%,
        rgba(47, 68, 95, 1) 2%,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 5%,
        rgb(54, 80, 114) 5%,
        rgba(39, 48, 56, 1) 9%,
        rgba(107, 149, 177, 1) 50%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 86%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 94%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 94%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 97%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 97%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 99%
  );
}

div.two.alt {  
    background: linear-gradient(
        140deg,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 2%,
        rgba(47, 68, 95, 1) 2%,
        rgba(40, 49, 56, 1) 5%,
        rgb(54, 80, 114) 5%,
        rgba(39, 48, 56, 1) 9%,
        rgba(107, 149, 177, 1) 50%,transparent 0
        ),
       linear-gradient(140deg,
        rgba(107, 149, 177, 1) 50%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 86%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 94%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 94%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 97%,
        rgba(249, 202, 180, 1) 97%,
        rgba(252, 220, 205, 1) 99%
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="two alt"></div>
```